# Open new browser tab from button click in java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to put write a javascript function behind a button so that when I press the button it will open a new tab and calls on the report_handler which opens the report.

My code behind this button currently is;

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btn_Print" runat="server" Text="Print" UseSubmitBehavior="false" AutoPostBack="false" RenderMode="Link" OnClick="btn_Print_Click">
<ClientSideEvents  Click="function(s, e) {'javascript:window.open(Report_Handler.ashx?')}"  /></dx:ASPxButton>
```

However this doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I've removed the OnClick event now and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

```
<ClientSideEvents  Click="javascript:window.open('Report_Handler.ashx?','_blank');"/>
```